# tell TextEdit left click "selected text" to open contextual menu

Tags: applescript, automator, textedit

I'm trying to build a shortcut for quick text sharing (selected text) from TextEdit to Notes and I need this last one step to create a workflow in Automator

[image: screenshotTextEdit]

I wonder if you guys have done something similar before or if you actually know an easier way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, in your system préférences / keyboard short cut / Service, there is a function "create a note" which is assigned to keys (shift command y). Then you just have to simulate these key in Applescript as bellow :

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate -- assume your text is already selected
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Y" using command down
```

Your selected text will be copied in a new note.

Answer (score 0):

What is simplest for an automator service is to create the call to the desired application. Below the pre-use script that copies the text selected in TexEdit to the ClipBoard then opens the Notes application and finishes by using the Edit menu and Paste menu in the Notes application. It has to work pretty well quite often.   (Change the names in the menu, I think it should be Paste and Edit)

```
  on run {input, parameters}
        activate application "Notes"
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notes"
         try            
          keystroke "c" using command down
            set frontmost to true
            click menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
           end try
        end tell
        return input
         end run
```